# Chrome extension development: Notification when a page is opened in the background page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I come from a mobile development background and I'm making my first chrome extension.

I need my extension to log the opened page to a server. Can I achieve this just by having a background page (Some event that gets triggered whenever a new page is opened)? Or do I need a content script that passes the message to the background page whenever it gets notified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [chrome.tabs.onCreated](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onCreated) in the background page to get notified when new tabs are opened.